# Android - which settings control the picture and text seen when browsing my phone's apps

Tags: android

I recently realized that the way my app icon and text look in the app store are actually different than how they appear in my app list after the app has been installed.

How can I control the app name and icon that appear when browsing the apps which have been downloaded to my phone?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon and title of the app on the actual phone are controlled from you app's AndroidManifext.xml file, specifically:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" > 

........
```

Note the `android:icon` and `android:label` attributes.  Icon is normally an image in your `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-ldpi` and, possibly, `drawable-xhdpi`.  The title (label) is a string from your string resources.  Specifically, all of these are part of the actual application, which is downloaded on end users' devices.

On Android Market (or now Android Play), you actually specify the title and icon you want to be shown when you create or edit an application from the control panel.  Here you can specify any title you want.  Also here, you upload a 512x512 image representing the icon of your application.

While the icon and title you specify in the control panel do not have to be the same as the ones in the application, it's usually a good idea to have them the same as to avoid any confusion for your end users.

Comment: thank - just one question...I got confused how to make sure the store icon is same as the app icon. Is that configurable in the store settings? Or I have to point to some image in the manifest?

Comment: @GeekedOut when you configure the app in the Android Play developer panel, there's an option to upload a 512x512 image of your icon.  I usually create the icon as 512x512 image first - for the Market - and then scale it down to be used in the app itself.

Comment: yeah but my confusion is how can I use that same icon in the app itself? Which configuration is it? :) Thanks!

Comment: @GeekedOut You create an icon - 512x512 - upload it to the market when you create/edit the app.  Then you scale that icon down to sizes 96x96 (xhdpi), 72x72 (hdpi), 48x48 (mdpi) and 36x36 (ldpi) - and include these four into the app itself.  Then you reference that icon in your manifest.  For more information, read the documentation on google: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size